# Health System using hearts in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I got this script and try to add a way for the player to lose hearts. I am not sure if I am missing anything. I tried the script, but nothing happened. This is also for a 2d platformer, and the main thing is I just want the player to lose a heart if he falls. Please help.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
 // Attach to an empty GameObject
 // To initialize script on a new scene, add updateHealthUI() in the Awake 
 or Start Method of your player
 // Then just use this script in your OnCollision method using 
 thisScript.Health --
 public class PlayerHealth : MonoBehaviour // MonoBehaviour
 {

  // Insert your 3 hearts images in the Unity Editor
public Image h1, h2, h3;
// Create an array because we're lazy
public Image[] images;
// Gameover
[SerializeField] private Image gameOver;
// A private variable to keep between scenes
int health = 3;
// Now we define Get / Set methods for health
// In case we Set health to a different value we want to update UI
public int Health { get { return health; } set { if (health != Health) 
health = Health; updateHealthUI(); } }

public void Awake()
{
    DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
    images = new Image[] { h1, h2, h3 };
    if (transform.position.y == -80)
    {
        health--;
    }
}
private void updateHealthUI()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < images.Length; i++)
    {
        // Hide all images superior to the newHealth
        if (i >= health)
            images[i].enabled = false;
        else
            images[i].enabled = true;
    }
    // Game Over
    if (health == 0)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
    }
}
void Update()
{
    if (health == 3)
    {
        images = new Image[] { h1, h2, h3 };
    }
    else if (health == 2)
    {
        images = new Image[] { h1, h2 };
    }
    else if (health == 1)
    {
        images = new Image[] { h1 };
    }


    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to decrease the health in [Awake](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Awake.html). The problem is that `Awake` is called only once during the lifetime of the script instance. So, try to put that if statement into the `Update` method instead of `Awake`:

```
if (transform.position.y == -80)
{
    health--;
}
```

Comment: @Daniel glad that your problem is solved. If you found this answer helpful, you may consider picking it as the answer to the problem so that other people who might face similar issues will see this on top.